# How to configure GNU Autotools to compile a program in 32-bit while on Centos7?

Tags: gcc, g++, centos7, 32bit-64bit, autotools

I'm doing all this on a VLE and below is what I'm working with:

Running OS: `Linux Centos 7`

GCC:`4.8.5 & 7.1.0`

I'm trying to use `GNU autotools (libtool, autoconf, automake)` to build a project in 32-bit using `gcc-7.1.0.` Also, as a requirement, I must do this on `Centos 7` and use `gcc-7.1.0.`

Apparently, the latest version of `gcc` that can be officially upgraded through `yum` is `4.8.5`. However, I successfully installed gcc-7.1.0 from the official source and even included `--enable-multiarch --with-list-multilib=m32,m64 --enable-multilib` during `configure`.

The issue I'm running into is that the `autotools` seem to want to use the 64-bit libraries even though I'm including -m32 compiler switch in `CXXFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS`. The reason I think it's using 64-bit libraries at linking is that I get the error below:

```
libtool: link: g++ -m32 -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -Werror -std=c++03 -O2 -o fldprog fldprog-icpprog.o  ../../                                                                                                                                                                 ../seal3/fld/src/.libs/libbsp_fld.a -lpci /usr/local/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib                                                                                                                                                                 /../lib64 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib/../lib64
/usr/local/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

*And* when I rename `/usr/local/lib64` to `lib64_something`, the program will compile without any errors. However, I want to find a permanent solution.

I've searched the internet for answers but none of them seem to really work. I've tried including -`L/usr/local/lib` to `AM_LDFLAGS`, `AM_CFLAGS` in `configure.ac`

I'd appreciate any input. Thank you.

**Edit:Revised**

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with the GCC 7 toolchain, not the Autotools.  Can you successfully build 32-bit executables by running the compiler and linker directly?

Comment: And if so, have a look at `make`'s output (be sure to run in verbose mode) to see what differences there are between the build commands `make` is running (that fail) and those that work for you when you issue them directly.